# Calling Jquery accordion on google maps only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-accordion

So I've created a google maps page with a bunch of markers generated from XML. The idea is that when you click on a marker a div will be generated that displays events information related to that marker. This all works fine but what I'm struggling with is now trying to attach an accordion to the events information. The code I have so far will show an accordion on the first marker you click on (can be any one and it returns the correct info, shows the div and has an accordion) but not on any subsequent marker clicks, even the same one for a second click.

I'm sure this must be a simple fix but I've tried a few variations (there are three attempts at the accordion that I have left in to show the different versions) and I am getting the same results.

Here is the code that binds the events to the markers as a google event listener..

```
function bindEvents(marker, id, venueName, website){
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){

    // TARGET and show eventsFeed on click
    $('#eventsFeed').show(222);
    var eventsList = document.getElementById('eventsList');


    // ADDS styles to the events feed divs when created
    // DECLARED here for the inclusion of the venueName & website as feedhead
    // even when no events are present
    var venueNameDiv = "<div class='venueNameFeed'>";
    var webSiteDiv = "<a target='_blank' class='websiteInFeed' href='http://"+website+"'><span class='fa fa-home'></span></a>";
    var titleInFeed = "<div class='"+id+" eventTitleFeed'>";
    var accordDataWrap = "<h2 class='accordWrap>";
    var eventInFeed = "<div class='eventDescFeed'>";
    var dateInFeed = '<div class="eventDateFeed">';
    var priceInFeed = "<div class='eventPriceFeed'>";
    // CLOSE the divs after each entry
    var divBrk = "</div>";
    var closeAccordDataWrap = "</h2>";
    var feedHead = venueNameDiv + venueName + divBrk;


    // EMPTY array to line up matched events in
    var eventsLine = [];

    // CYCLE through eventsArray
    for (var key in eventsArray){

        var eventLoop = eventsArray[key];

        // MATCH id to venue_id
        var venue_id = eventLoop.venue_id;
        if (venue_id == id){

            // ONLY show events from todays date onward
            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(eventLoop.eventDATE);
            // SET hours to 0 to ignore time part (always as 01:00:00 for event date?)
            now.setHours(0,0,0,0);  

            if (date >= now){

                //ADD all matched events to eventsLine array
                eventsLine.push(titleInFeed + eventLoop.eventTitle + divBrk + 
                    accordDataWrap + eventInFeed + eventLoop.event + divBrk + 
                    dateInFeed + formatDate(eventLoop.eventDATE) + divBrk +
                    priceInFeed + "£" + eventLoop.price + divBrk + closeAccordDataWrap);
            }
        }
    }

    // TURNS the array into a string and replaces those damned, infernal commas!!
    var outputString = eventsLine.toString().replace(/>,/g, '>');


    // PUT the compiled array into the eventsFeed div (with venueName as title)
    if (website==""){
        eventsList.innerHTML = feedHead + outputString;
    } else {
        eventsList.innerHTML = feedHead + webSiteDiv + outputString;
    }

    // ADD the accordion

   $(document).on('click', marker, function(){
       $(eventsList).accordion({
           header: "div."+id,
           icons: null
       })
   })
```

//       OR

```
    $(eventsList).each(function(){
        $(eventsList).accordion({
            header: "div."+id,
            icons: null
        });
    });
```

//        OR

```
accordion(eventsList, id);

});
```

}

This third option calls a separate function which is defined as;

```
function accordion(placement,id){

$(placement).accordion({
    header: "div."+id,
    icons: null
});
```

}

As you can probably tell I'm pretty new to all of this so any help or advice with anything would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this code:

```
$(eventsList).each(function(){
    $(eventsList).accordion({
        header: "div."+id,
        icons: null
    });
});
```

with this code:

```
$(eventsList).each(function(){
    $(this).accordion({
        header: "div."+id,
        icons: null
    });
});
```

and try. Also it will be better if you can [Create a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code.